# Ocaml Type Mismatch? Expected Unit but is a defined type

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, functional-programming, ocaml

I get the error below and I cannot figure out why this is the case. any help is appreciated. the program is an interpreter in Ocaml. The piece of code being underlined by tryOcaml is the last bit of code "processor tokens [];;" Not sure why that would be the type mismatch or where the mismatch happens in the code.

Error: This expression has type stackValue list
but an expression was expected of type unit

```
type stackValue = NUM of int | BOOL of bool | ERROR | STRING of string | NAME of string | UNIT

type com = PUSH of stackValue | POP | ADD | SUB | MUL | DIV | REM | NEG | SWAP | QUIT | TOSTRING | PRINTLN (*| CAT | AND | OR | NOT | LESSTHAN | EQUAL | IF | BIND let com {com} end | funBind com {com} [return] funEnd | call*)

let interpreter ( (inFile : string), (outFile : string )) : unit = 
let ic = open_in inFile 
in
let oc = open_out outFile 
in

let rec loop_read acc =
  try 
      let l = String.trim(input_line ic) in loop_read (l::acc)
  with
  | End_of_file -> List.rev acc 
  in

  let ls_str = loop_read [] 
  in
let checkrest s = 
  match s.[0] with
  | '"' ->  if s.[(String.length s) -1]='"' then STRING(String.sub s 1 ((String.length s)-2)) else ERROR
  | '-' | '0'..'9' -> (try NUM(int_of_string s) with _ ->ERROR)
  | '_' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' -> NAME(s)
  |_ -> ERROR
  in

  let str2sv s =
    match s with
    |":true:" -> BOOL(true)
    |":false:" -> BOOL(false)
    |":unit:" -> UNIT
    |":error:" -> ERROR
    |_-> checkrest s 
    in

  let str2com s = 
    match s with 
    |"quit" -> QUIT
    |"add" -> ADD
    |"sub" -> SUB
    |"mul" -> MUL
    |"div" -> DIV
    |"rem" -> REM
    |"pop" -> POP
    |"neg" -> NEG
    |"swap" -> SWAP
    (*|"cat" -> CAT
    |"and" -> AND
    |"or" -> OR
    |"not" -> NOT
    |"lessthan" -> LESSTHAN
    |"equal" -> EQUAL
    |"if" -> IF
    |"bind" -> BIND*)
    |"toString" -> TOSTRING
    |_ -> if String.sub s 0 4 = "push" then let x = str2sv (String.sub s 5 ((String.length s) -5)) in PUSH(x) else PUSH(ERROR)
    in

let tokens = List.map str2com ls_str
in

let sv2str sv =
  match sv with
  |BOOL(true) -> STRING(":true:")
  |BOOL(false) -> STRING(":false:")
  |UNIT -> STRING(":unit:")
  |ERROR -> STRING(":error:")
  |STRING(s) -> STRING(s)
  |NAME(s) -> STRING(s)
  |NUM(x) -> STRING(string_of_int(x))
in

let file_write value = Printf.fprintf oc "%s\n" value 
in

let rec processor comlist stack =
  match (comlist,stack) with
  |(PUSH(x)::comst, stack) -> processor comst (x::stack)
  |(POP::comst, stackValue::reststack) -> processor comst reststack
  |(POP::comst, []) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(ADD::comst, NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack) -> processor comst (NUM(a+b)::reststack)
  |(ADD::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(SUB::comst, NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack) -> processor comst (NUM(b-a)::reststack)
  |(SUB::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(MUL::comst, NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack) -> processor comst (NUM(a*b)::reststack)
  |(MUL::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(DIV::comst, NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack) -> if (NUM(a)=NUM(0)) then (processor comst (ERROR::NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack)) else (processor comst (NUM(b/a)::reststack))
  |(DIV::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(REM::comst, NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack) -> if (NUM(a)=NUM(0)) then (processor comst (ERROR::NUM(a)::NUM(b)::reststack)) else (processor comst (NUM(b mod a)::reststack))
  |(REM::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(NEG::comst, NUM(a)::reststack) -> processor comst (NUM(-a)::reststack)
  |(NEG::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(SWAP::comst, x::xs::reststack) -> processor comst (xs::x::reststack)
  |(SWAP::comst, stack) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(TOSTRING::comst, x::reststack) -> let s = sv2str x in processor comst (s::reststack)
  |(TOSTRING::comst, []) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(PRINTLN::comst, x::reststack) -> (match x with 
                                        |STRING(x) -> file_write x; processor comst reststack
                                        |_ -> ERROR::stack)
  |(PRINTLN::comst, []) -> processor comst (ERROR::stack)
  |(QUIT::comst, stack) -> []
  |(_,_) -> []

in
processor tokens [];;
```

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? You specify that the `interpreter` function should return `unit`, but the last expression in it is a call to the `processor` function which returns a `stackValue list`. Hence a type mismatch.

Comment: how do i return a unit i guess? not sure how  i can return a unit, i dont really need the unit for anything because this program functions like a void function and handles things all inside processor. i am very new to Ocaml and this kind of functionality is not my forte.

Answer (score 1):

Let me minimize your code to highlight the problem,

```
let interpreter ( (inFile : string), (outFile : string )) : unit = 
  ... <snip> ...
let rec processor comlist stack =
  match (comlist,stack) with
  |(PUSH(x)::comst, stack) -> processor comst (x::stack)
  |(QUIT::comst, stack) -> []
  ... <snip> ...
  |(_,_) -> []

in
processor tokens []
```

Take a second and look carefully at the snippet above, do you see the problem? If not yet, then answer the following questions:

1. What type of value does `processor` function return?
2. What type of value the `interpreter` shall return?

E.g., consider `processor [] []`, it will return `[]` therefore we can see that `processor tokens []` is a value of type `_ list`, but you have an annotation `: unit` that says that your `interpreter input output` shall evaluate to a value of type `unit` where instead it evaluates to a stack.

If you really don't need the stack, you can ignore it,

```
ignore (processor tokens [])
```

where `ignore` is a simple function, that has roughly the following implementation,

```
let ignore x = ()
```

i.e., it just ignores its argument so that it has type `'a -> unit`. Instead of using `ignore` you can also write,

```
let _stack = processor tokens [] in
()
```

So you ignore the returned stack (the convention is to prefix with an underscope an ignored value) and return the `()` value instead of the `_stack`.

Comment: so does ignore just execute the function and then throw away the return form the function inside the parenthesis? i put that in and that error went away, but i have another error. "Error: Illegal character (\r)" i have seen this last night, but i do not know what i did to fix it. GREAT help with ignore, never knew it was a thing

Comment: Yes, `ignore` evaluates its expression and then essentially throws away the result. You should open a new question if you haven't figure out your new problem. There's no way to tell what's going on just from the error message. It is not illegal to have `'\r'`(carriage return)  in your source code in general. So the context is iimportant.

Comment: You may think it this way, but it is just a function. OCaml is an eager language and every time you write a function application, e.g., `print_int 42` is executed immediately, no matter if it is passed to another function or ignored. Basically, the OCaml mechanics (or semantics in scholar speech) is to execute all function applications until nothing is left :) I've updated the answer with more details.